# Popup Sub form data not saving to form

Tags: ms-access

I have created a tabbed main form with sub forms.  I set one of the tabs visibility properties to invisible and use a command button to open said form. When I open the subform with command button and enter data, the data does not save to the form but does save to the table.  The reason I am using this method is that the sub form is a log and it is easier for the users.  The Master Child fields are correct and so are the table relations.  Can anyone shed some light on this? Thank you is advance for any assistance.  Oh and I am using 2016

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the issue or not but consider looking at the Forms Property Sheet and double check that you have Data Entry set to "No" and all the "Allow" properties set to yes.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this but unfortunately that is not the issue as the form's properties are set how you said.  I checked and it works as it should if I use the sub form as a visible tab but not as a pop up.  I really want it to work as a pop up though!  HA!